# When does the transistor reach the stable status when I add resistor to the emitter

Tags: voltage, transistors, semiconductors, stability

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fPreZZ.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If I add resistor R3, which is an emiter resistor, can it change the value of the base voltage? I've learned that the emmiter voltage follows the base voltage that it is always Ve = Vb - 0,7 V.

My next question is: why does it work like that ?

When the R3 wants more current then R2's voltage drops as well. Let's say Vb = 2 V. Adding R3, the voltage will drop to Vb = 1.3 V, because R3 requires more current.

But if R3 requires more current then the voltage of Vb drops and less current will flow to R3 which will then require less current so the base current can again go up and when it raises, Vb raises as well, then the R3 will require more current and the cycle begins.

When will this will reach stability? I am confused intuitively because I know how to calculate it using KCV, but I don't understand it conceptually.

The picture is just an example of my problem; the values are random.

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142896/discussion-on-question-by-user331990-when-does-the-transistor-reach-the-stable-s); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.